# ArgumentError in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Can anyone tell me why i'm getting the following error while running devise
ArgumentError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing

```
C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h2>Sign in</h2>
2: 
3: <%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
5:   <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
6:
```